# Azure Deployement Failed

Tags: azure, .net-core

Since last month I am doing successful deployment on azure using visual Studio on Azure function App but suddenly I am start getting error while deploying.

> Web deployment task failed. (Unable to perform the operation ("Create File")  for the specified directory ("D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\extensions.json")

I tried following things but in vain.

1. I restarted my Function app
2. Reset the publish key

> Updating file (MobiMatterUsers\bin\extensions.json). C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\PublishTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(140,5):
>   error : Web deployment task failed. (Unable to perform the operation
>   ("Create File")  for the specified directory
>   ("D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\extensions.json"). This can occur if the
>   server administrator has not authorized this operation for the user
>   credentials you are using.

Kindly provide me possible solution and brief explanation why i am getting this error

Comment: Please provide us your YAML or build definition. Otherwise we could not help you, as you are only showing errors, not how you get the error and what is the build pipelines you have.

Comment: I am deploying directly from visual studio by publishing it using profile key of function app

Comment: Then this is not related to Azure DevOps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IAM in the portal to see if you have the required rights.

Then rename the old file as it may be locked by a process.

if that doesn't work, check it local deployment still works.